# Why is this line of code causing an error in HTML validator?

Tags: php, html

I'm writing a website that needs to be W3C compliant. Everything is validated correctly until I use PHP tags. This line of code specifically: `<?php include 'menu.html'; ?>` The error given is:

`Saw <?. Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing instruction in HTML. (XML processing instructions are not supported in HTML.)`

How can this be fixed?

Comment: _"How can this be fixed?"_ - by not validating unparsed PHP code, which makes no sense to begin with. What you should validate, is the _HTML output_ that your script created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PHP is server-based, users cannot see PHP codes.
Those PHP tags should not show up in your markup.
As far as I understand, you are trying to include php in the html file. That's why you're getting an error.

To solve this:

You can change your file extension to .php and run it on server.

or

Instead of including the menu.html file; You can copy and paste the menu html codes into the include line.